# have a issue with sql statement c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am using db4free.net, The server is slow and sometimes times out instead of connecting. all i need to know is how to disable or avoid the error message. If anyone knows a better free hosting site it would be appreciated.

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
MySqlDataReader dr;
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE USERNAME = '" +      
    "username" + "'AND PASSWORD = '" + "password" + "'";

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dr.Read();

if (dr.HasRows)
{
}    
else
{
}
```

when i have a timeout to the server the error comes from dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

Comment: You can control the timeout used by a command with the property CommandTimeout

Comment: To speed things up you can add an index to your table, SELECT specific fields instead of using * and I would use parameters to avoid sql injection. The latter is for security no necessarily for speed.

Comment: ^^ That should help. And please consider using `parameterized queries` and `using` statements. You can also use `try - catch` block for exception handling.

Comment: ok  thanks and theres no better sites i can use for hosting? takes forever to add  a account lol

Answer (score 2):

1 - You should use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection.

2 - You can use a try catch block to handle the timeout.

3 - You should put the command in a 'using' statement because MySqlCommand implements IDisposable.

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE USERNAME = @username AND PASSWORD = @password";
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", "password");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", "username");

    try
    {
        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
    catch (TimeoutException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        // or whatever you want to do with a timeout
        // perhaps retry again or give a message to the user
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well to be honest based on you code you have a lot more problems than the server speed.

The simplest solution to your problem will be to set the SqlCommand.CommandTimeout property to something larger than the default 30 seconds. 0 will mean an indefinite period...something like 120 seconds will be far more than any user would put up with.

Then you look at the concatenation in the command text...just asking for a sql injection attack.

Then you look at the fact you are passing the password in as well. At best that means the passwords are have a fixed salt, at worst that they are plain text.

You should query for the user record based on username only, using a parameterized query. This field should be indexed in your database to improve the query performance. As part of registration you should have generated a per user salt which was used to hash the password.

Having retrieved the salt you should then hash the user supplied password and compare them.

Comment: ya your right they are plain text but this is a work in progress eventually i wil work my way to encryption

Comment: That's the best way to never implement it properly

Comment: @Ragekillen I know it looks hard before you've tried it, but it's just as simple as hashing the value the user passes and storing the hashed value for some basic security in case your database gets compromised (which will absolutly happen if you don't parameterize your inputs).  I don't mean to nag you about security stuff when you're just trying to learn the basics, but it's not too complicated and it's a good idea to get into the habit of it.

Comment: As a side note. Whilst indexing your username field may help with your db timeout, it could actually lead to user enumeration via a timing side channel attack. However you should concentrate on a per user salt and hashed password as a minimum.

Comment: Also I hear good things about http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/ if you want to let a library handle the heavy lifting

Answer (score 0):

use

```
cmd.CommandTimeout = int.MaxValue;
```

Comment: This method will only hide the underlying problem. Use of a try-catch block will better solve the problem.

Comment: Wouldnt want to be one of your users waiting for that timeout

Answer (score 0):

Increase timeout of your command execution. Use [DbCommand.CommandTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) to change default timeout.

By default timeout is **30 seconds** which is good for most cases. You can set it to **'0' - no timeout**. However, I suggest to choose some optimal value for your environment.

```
cmd.CommandTimeout = 300; // Value in seconds
```

Comment: Command timeout is in seconds https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx